# Regex: Javascript, XML, String

Tags: javascript, regex, xml, soap

I have the following data in a variable.

```
<ctx>
  <PostCode>XXXXXX</PostCode>
  <Title1>Mr</Title1>
  <Name>John</Name>
  <Order1>£100.00</Order1>
  <Order2>£100.01</Order2>
  <Date>10/10/2010</Date
</ctx>
```

Using the following regex `var payload = ctx.toString().match(/Order[1-9]/g);` I get the following results

> Order1,Order1,Order2,Order2

How can I make it stop at Order1, Order2 as is counting the second closing tag, also I can't use `<Order[1-9]>` (opening tag) as my application does not allow me to capture the tags `<>`. **Basically a regex that returns unique values.**

So the following regex seems to work to some extend. `(Order[0-9])(?!.*\1)`
[image: (Order[0-9])(?!.*\1)]

https://regex101.com/r/6QhFBg/1

Answer (score 2):

**Never parse XML with regex.**  Wrong tool for the job – leads to brittle solutions.

Instead, use a real XML parser or XPath.

For example, this XPath,

```
//*[starts-with(local-name(), 'Order')]
```

will robustly select all elements whose name starts with `"Order"`.

In JavaScript in the browser, XPath expressions are evaluated via `document.evaluate`:

```
var orders = document.evaluate('//Order[starts-with(local-name(), 'Order')]', document, 
                               null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null );
var thisOrder = orders.iterateNext();

while (thisOrder) {
  console.log(thisOrder.textContent);
  thisOrder = orders.iterateNext();
}
```

See also [How to use document.evaluate() and XPath to get a list of elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36303869/290085)

For parsing XML stored in a string, see for example:

- [XML parsing of a variable string in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/649614/290085)
- [Parse XML using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17604071/290085)

Answer (score 1):

```js
let ctx = 
`<ctx>
  <PostCode>XXXXXX</PostCode>
  <Title1>Mr</Title1>
  <Name>John</Name>
  <Order1>£100.00</Order1>
  <Order2>£100.01</Order2>
  <Date>10/10/2010</Date
</ctx>`;

let payload = ctx
  .match(/<Order[1-9]>/g) // e.g. <Order1>
  .map(o => o.substring(1, o.length - 1)); // trim first char `<` and last char `>`

console.log(payload);
```

Comment: Thanks, this would have worked if my application allowed me to capture the whole payload structure including tags and anchors `<>`, but I can't use `<Order[1-9]>`

Comment: Did you read the next line (`.map(...`)? It removes the `<` and `>`.

Comment: Is there a regex variant that matches Order[1-9] but only returns unique values.

Comment: Regex isn't going to do operations like 'find uniques' or 'map integers to double their value'. But that's where `js` comes in.