# Uncaught TypeError: $x is not a function on Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am using this syntax to test xpath via console, and generally it works in most websites and GoogleSheets is one of the few exceptions I faced so far.

If I recall well, when it didn't work on some other websites, it was due to missing jQuery which is not the case here.

Could anyone explain what this issue and fix here ?

```js
$x("//body")
```

- Sample page to test from your end: (Not my link, but found on the internet)

  - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JCEHwIa4ZzwAiKGmAnWGfbjeVCH_tWZF6MkIU0zICwM/edit#gid=0
- Sample error while css selector syntax works fine:

  [image]
- That xpath is so simple and it works fine when searching in the Elements tab

  [image]
- I have chrome up to date under Win10 x64

  [image]

Comment: Devtools adds `$x` and `$` as global functions so when a site has a symbol with such names the site's version is used. There's no solution AFAIK. See [How to use document.evaluate() and XPath to get a list of elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36303869)

Comment: Too sad, I thought Devtools injects those functions when not found. It seems logical but maybe there is reason not to. Anyway, this answers the question, thank you for the input.